# Is there any difference between using async* and yield* or not on returning FirebaseFirestore QuerySnapshot

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Is there any difference between the first case and the second case?

**1.**

```dart
Stream<QuerySnapshot> streamUsersOne() async* {
  yield* FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots();
}
```

**2.**

```dart
Stream<QuerySnapshot> streamUsersTwo() {
  return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots();
}
```

Comment: Do both compile? I'd expect that first one to give an error, as the return types don't match (but am definitely not an expert on `yield*` in Dart).

Comment: yes. Both work fine

Answer (score 0):

This first one(async* and yield) is used when you are creating your own Stream and it has no need to use it here because the snapshots method has already return type of Stream.
you can watch this   [clip](https://youtube.com/clip/UgkxpOaywDHRAw4f0EHLJhEN4JKirEYbZjRN) to learn more about how to create a stream.

Comment: Thanks for answer! I have one question, does the first one create a new stream?

Comment: watch this you will get the answer https://youtu.be/hnNJXOXiURo?t=1130

Comment: I watched it, but I'm sorry, I don't get it.